# Converting String to local variable instead using switch

Tags: c#

I know it sound a bit weird but is it possible to convert string to local variable like this :

```
String actionName = "eat";
(local variable)actionName;

Pet.actionName;
//and computer will read it as Pet.eat;
```

in switch it would look like that:

```
String actionName = "eat";

switch (actionName)
{
    eat:
       return  Pet.eat;
    default:
       return;
}
```

Comment: It's not as easy on local variables, but if you have a class (which you seem to have), you can use reflection. You'll find tutorials to no end about it on Google.

Comment: What are you asking??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *reflection*:

```
  String actionName = "eat"; // Actually, property/field name 

  // looks like you want to get static property
  // without creating Pet instance 
  var result = typeof(Pet).GetProperty(actionName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null);
```

If `actionName` is in fact a *field* (not *property*) the syntax should be changed a little:

```
var result = typeof(Pet).GetField(actionName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null);
```

Edit: if `Pet` is just a *enum*, you can just *parse* it

```
  String actionName = "eat";
  Pet result = (Pet) (Enum.Parse(typeof(Pet), actionName));
```

Comment: this is enum type to be precise

Comment: @MTo: if `Pet` is just a *enum* all you need is to *parse* it (see my edit)